# Automapper: Avoid mapping source members without destination member to its abstract base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

**Question:**
I have two classes (source and destination) with dto's which inherit from a abstract base class. When I try to map a list with source members to the destination dto's AutoMapper tries to map the missing mapping relation ship to the abstract destination class. How can I avoid this problem?

**Information:** It's not possible to make sure that all source members have their destination "partner".

These are the source member classes:

```
namespace Source
{
   public abstract class Item
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public int Size { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
   }
   public class Asset1 : Item{}
   public class Asset2 : Item{}
}
```

These are the destination member classes:

```
namespace Destination
{
   public abstract class ItemDto
   {
       public int ProductId { get; set; }
       public int Size { get; set; }
       public string ProductName { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
   }
   public class Asset1Dto : ItemDto{}
}
```

This is the AutoMapper Configuration:

```
 namespace AutoMapper
 {
   public class MappingProfile : Profile
   {
       public MappingProfile()
       {
          CreateMap<Item, ItemDto>(MemberList.Destination)
               .Include<Asset1, Asset1Dto>()
               .ForMember(o => o.ProductId, ex => ex.MapFrom(o => o.Id))
               .ForMember(o => o.ProductName, ex => ex.MapFrom(o => o.Name))
               .ReverseMap();

           CreateMap<Asset1, Asset1Dto>(MemberList.Destination).ReverseMap();            
       }
    }
 }
```

This is the Main-Class:

```
namespace AutoMapperExample
{
   public class Program
   {
       private static IList<Item> _items;
       private static IMapper _mapper;


       private static void Config()
       {
           _items = new List<Item>();
           var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
           {
               cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
           });
           _mapper = new Mapper(config);
       }

       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           Config();

           // Create dummy content
           var rnd = new Random().Next();

           _items.Add(new Asset1()
           {
               Name = typeof(Asset1).ToString(),
               Id = rnd,
               Size = 23,
               Description = "Dummy-Text 1"
           });

           // working case
           Console.WriteLine("Working when relation is present:");
           try
           {
               var itemDto = _mapper.Map<IList<ItemDto>>(_items);
               var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(itemDto);
               Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(e);
               throw;
           }
           Console.WriteLine();

           rnd = new Random().Next();
           _items.Add(new Asset2()
           {
               Name = typeof(Asset2).ToString(),
               Id = rnd,
               Size = 23,
               Description = "Dummy-Text 2"
           });

           // case which throws the exception
           Console.WriteLine("No destination member present:");
           try
           {
              var itemDto = _mapper.Map<IList<ItemDto>>(_items);
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(e);
           }
       }
   }
```

}

Exception I get:

> ---> System.ArgumentException: Cannot create an instance of abstract type ItemDto

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Nimrasol/328292f0c7724083f184ab0df54aa831) repo with the example code.

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/Nimrasol/328292f0c7724083f184ab0df54aa831) where you can find my example code for my problem. I hope you can help me. I have the feeling that the solution is rater simple.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping for `Asset2` doesn't work because you didn't configure it anywhere. You just need to add it, the same as with `Asset1`.

```
c.CreateMap<Item, ItemDto>()
                .Include<Asset1, Asset1Dto>()
                .Include<Asset2, Asset1Dto>()
                .ForMember(o => o.ProductId, ex => ex.MapFrom(o => o.Id))
                .ForMember(o => o.ProductName, ex => ex.MapFrom(o => o.Name))
                .ReverseMap();
c.CreateMap<Asset1, Asset1Dto>().ReverseMap();
c.CreateMap<Asset2, Asset1Dto>(MemberList.Destination).ReverseMap();
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear enough. Asset2 can't be mapped to Asset1Dto. These are two totally different objects in reality. No destination class for Asset2 is available. I'm looking for a way to "ignore" the Asset2 object in case no destination partner is available.

Comment: `c.CreateMap<Asset2, ItemDto>().ConvertUsing(s=>null);`

Comment: This solution produces a null entry in the destination list. Furthermore, I need to define this for all the incoming members. Unfortunately I haven't a complete list of source members. I kneed a more general solution if available.

Comment: Write the code you need in C#, without AM, then try to see is it has anything to do with AM, because I'm not sure it has :)

Comment: A map from `object` to `ItemDto` might work, but the whole thing is just weird. It sounds like business logic, not mapping.

Comment: I don't understand the confusion. Is it really so special when I have more classes on the source side than on the destination side? without the abstract mother class it wouldn't be an issue at all...

Comment: It's no confusion :) It simply doesn't make any sense as mapping. I'm sure it does make sense once you know your domain. AM is for mapping, not for business rules. I'm sure you can do it with AM, but this belongs inside your app logic, not in AM.

Comment: Ok, get it. Do you have any suggestion how how I can solve this correctly?

Comment: You should write the business logic part outside AM and then do the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

@lucian-bargaoanu: According to your statement it's not possible to implement AutoMapper in a way to map the source class structure into the destination class structure (see image below) without getting an exception? If this statement is true, how can I solve the problem without adding a "Asst2Dto" class?

Thank you so much for your help!

**Desired mapping operation:**

```
        var itemList = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Asset1(),
            new Asset2(),
        };

        var itemDtoList = _mapper.Map<List<ItemDto>>(itemList);
```

**Simplified source and target class diagram:**
[image]